# Scale functions dt(), qt(), pt(), and rt() in R

Tags: r, scale

Hello I would like to scale the functions `dt()`, `qt()`,`pt()`, and `rt()` in RStudio without using the library metRology and the functions `dt.scaled()`, `qt.scaled()`, `pt.scaled()`, and `rt.scaled()`. I got this for `dt()`

`1/sigma*dt((x - mu)/sigma, df = n-1)`

Can some one help me?

Comment: You can always just look at the source code for `dt.scaled`, etc. Install the package, load it with `library(metRology)` and then `dt.scaled`.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know you can do that in R!